# How to set additional cluster IPs in NLB through WMI

Tags: wmi, nlb

Microsoft NLB supports additional cluster IPs, does anyone know if I could get/set them through WMI? I've already looked at "root\MicrosoftNLB" "MicrosoftNLB_ClusterSetting" class, the "ClusterIPAddress" only returns the primary IP.

Appreciate any help!
Thanks,

Jillaint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. You can do this in PowerShell!

You can't really do anything with the additional clusterIP or VIP even though you could have multiple dedicated IP (DIP). Not sure whey they enhanced DIP but not VIP.